# android studio Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

erro details:

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/127.0.1.2] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Connection refused: connect

===============================================
android studio version is 3.0.1

the last error description:
Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/127.0.1.2] failed: Connection refused: connect

> Connection refused: connect

I had tried to add google() or maven{http://....} to build.gradle,it's not work as well. how to reslove it? thank you

=======================
build.gradle(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.



buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

```
 task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

=============================
build.gradle(Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "onlineconfig.umeng.gametools.com.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner       

"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {

 release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     

'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'

 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-         

core:3.0.1'
```

Comment: Please show the Gradle file

Comment: `Connection refused` sounds like you're being blocked

Comment: @cricket_007 here are two gradle file

Comment: Update your sdk

Answer (score 0):

Do you come from China, where Google is banned? That make you feel unbearably slow when visit many sites with Google services linked (for example, font.googleapis), then you searched and did some workaround, which was "modify hosts to point all the google-like sites to localhost".

You did that, then when your Gradle was trying to connect Google, it resolve https://dl.google.com as [127.0.1.2](http://127.0.1.2), which is a local loopback address.

> Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/127.0.1.2] failed: Connection refused: connect Connection refused: connect

To resolve this, just simply remove the lines related to Google in your `hosts` file.

If you still remain connection refused, please, learn how to "Surf the Internet **SCIENTIFICALLY**"

Comment: yes,but i have a vpn,i  will try to change hosts file,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the gradle from v7:26.1.0  to v7:26.+ which uses the needed version of library and android studio started working.